# Arduino accepting only alternate characters

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I am writing an Arduino code to receive SMS from a SIM800 module and then send the same message back to the sender. My code is as follows:

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(9, 10);//Connect to pin 9&10 on GSM module


const byte numChars = 128; //character size
char receivedChars[numChars]; // Store data read from SMS
boolean newData = false; //flag to check if new data has arrived

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 mySerial.begin(9600);
 Serial.println("<Arduino is ready>");
 mySerial.println("AT");
 mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1"); //text mode
 mySerial.println("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0");
 mySerial.println("AT+CSQ"); //Check signal strength
   while (Serial.available()) 
  {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());//Forward what Serial received to Software Serial Port
  }
  while(mySerial.available()) 
  {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());//Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port
  }
}

void loop() {
  //code for checking sms
  scanSMS();
  //Print if a new data arrived
  showNewData();
  delay(25000);
}

void scanSMS() {
    static boolean recvInProgress = false;
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char startMarker = '#'; //Start and end markers. Eg. SMS body will be sent as #status# 
    char endMarker = '#';
    char rc;
    while (Serial.available()) 
    {
      mySerial.write(Serial.read());//Forward what Serial received to Software Serial Port
    }

    while (mySerial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
      Serial.write(mySerial.read());//Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port

      rc = mySerial.read();

      if (recvInProgress == true) {
        if (rc != endMarker) {
          receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
          ndx++;
          if (ndx >= numChars) {
            ndx = numChars - 1;
          }
        }
        else {
          receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
          recvInProgress = false;
          ndx = 0;
          newData = true;
          }
        }
      else if (rc == startMarker) {
        recvInProgress = true;
      }
    }
}

/*PRINT IF THERE IS A NEW DATA*/
void showNewData() {
 if (newData == true) {
   SendMessage(receivedChars);
 newData = false;
 }
}

/*SEND BACK WHATEVER SMS IS RECEIVED*/
void SendMessage(String receivedChars)
{
  Serial.print("here");
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+xxxxxxxxxx\"\r"); // Replace x with mobile number
  mySerial.println("Humidity Alert!");// The SMS text you want to send
  mySerial.print(receivedChars);
   mySerial.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
}
```

The issue is that the module seems to receive only alternate characters instead of the whole message. For example, if I send the text #program#, the Arduino will only print porm or rga. Am I missing something here? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

```cpp
Serial.write(mySerial.read());
rc = mySerial.read();
```

Here you are calling `mySerial.read()` twice, and thus reading two
characters from the port's input buffer. You then forward the first
character through `Serial`, and process the second one. Note that you
should normally not read two characters unless you have tested that
`mySerial.available() >= 2`.

You probably want to forward and process one character at a time, thus
only call `mySerial.read()` once within this loop:

```cpp
rc = mySerial.read();  // read from mySerial
Serial.write(rc);      // forward through Serial
// now process rc
```